# Office 365 API - Authentication Error

Tags: owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, office365api

I have an Asp.Net Mvc app to which I have added Office 365 service. Azure Active Directory has been created and Username/Applications have been populated properly in the Azure portal.

I am able to login from the app and get the Authorization code. However when code is submitted to get the OAuth token, it throws AdalServiceException with "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." message.

I'm using Owin OpenIdConnect authentication for communicating Office365 API's. For this I'm injecting my authentication flow in Owin StartUp class, as shown below:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = AADAppSettings.ClientId,
                    Authority = AADAppSettings.Authority,

                    TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;

                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AADAppSettings.ClientId, AADAppSettings.AppKey);
                            string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/{1}", AADAppSettings.AuthorizationUri, tenantID), new NaiveSessionCache(signedInUserID));

                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code,
                                new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)),
                                credential,
                                AADAppSettings.AADGraphResourceId);
                                AuthenticationHelper.SetToken(result.AccessToken);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },                      

                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                        {
                            string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                            context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },

                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            // Suppress the exception
                            context.HandleResponse(); 

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }

                });
        }
```

Exception is thrown at below statement.

```
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code,
                                    new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)),
                                    credential,
                                    AADAppSettings.AADGraphResourceId);
```

Comment: can you post the values you are passing to the AuthenticationContext constructor and the call to AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode?

Comment: new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/9b0315c5-0ac6-44a7-****-************", new NaiveSessionCache(signedInUserID));

signedInUserID is the value of ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier

Comment: authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(<authorization code>,
                                new Uri("https://localhost:44312/",
                                new ClientCredential(<ClientId>, <ClientSecret>
                                "https://graph.windows.net/");

ClientId and ClientSecret are added in the Web.config automatically when we add the connected service.

Comment: The call to the auth context constructor lacks "HTTPS://"

Comment: Also, the uri in call to acquiretoken looks odd. Are those actual values or cut&paste issues?

Comment: All the URIs are valid, I am actually trying to run the Property Management app downloaded from below repository, without making any changes.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Property-Inspection-Code-Sample

Comment: Looking at the readme, it would appear you do need to update the URLs and other properties in order to run the demo in your environment- hence I am not sure what do you mean with "without making any changes".